# Interval between xlim

Tags: matlab, plot, simpledateformat, figure

I try to create simple figure with:

```
figure;
plot(sample_time,sample_value,'r--')
datetick
xlim([datenum('14-Aug-2005') datenum('28-Aug-2005')])
ylabel('Value (m)')
xlabel('Date (2005)')
```

where **sample_time** and **sample_value** is a variable <12385x1 double>.

However the displayed `xtick` is only 3 (08/14 08/21 08/28)

How to add more `xtick` ? (08/14 08/16 08/18 08/20 08/22 08/24 08/26 08/28)

I try to modify with `xtick` and `xlabel` but then the whole data is shown (the `xlim` effect is appended)

Can anybody gives me a solution, please?

Comment: I guess there would be a conflict if we use `datetick` and `xtick` together. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'08/14','08/16','08/18','08/20','08/22','08/24','08/26','08/28'})
```

Obviously, you can create the cell array programmatically based on your data rather than manually.

Comment: Thank you **@am304**. However I had try to do that but it still does not make any different. I also try to put additional line `set(gca,'XTick',{732538.0,732540.0,732542.0,732544.0,732546.0,732548.0,732550.0,732552.0})` but still come with same result.